# How to seperate JSON data

Tags: python, json, ibm-cloud, speech-recognition

I'm trying to make a simple SR program in python that recognizes speech. I'm using IBM cloud's api for this and I'm running into some problems.

```py
import json;
from os.path import join, dirname
from ibm_watson import SpeechToTextV1
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('KEY')
speech_to_text = SpeechToTextV1(
    authenticator=authenticator
)

speech_to_text.set_service_url('URL')

with open(join(dirname(__file__), './.', 'recording.mp3'),
               'rb') as audio_file:
    speech_recognition_results = speech_to_text.recognize(
        audio=audio_file,
        content_type='audio/mp3',
        word_alternatives_threshold=0.9,
        keywords=['um', 'uh', 'like'],
        keywords_threshold=0.5
    ).get_result()
print(json.dumps(speech_recognition_results, indent=2))
```

This code works perfectly fine but it is the output I am having trouble with.

```json
{
  "result_index": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "final": true,
      "alternatives": [
        {
          "transcript": "hello Ryan how are you today ",
          "confidence": 0.73
        }
      ],
      "word_alternatives": [
        {
          "start_time": 0.19,
          "end_time": 0.45,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "hello",
              "confidence": 0.93
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 0.45,
          "end_time": 0.99,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "Ryan",
              "confidence": 0.92
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 1.12,
          "end_time": 1.31,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "how",
              "confidence": 0.98
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 1.31,
          "end_time": 1.41,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "are",
              "confidence": 0.98
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 1.41,
          "end_time": 1.61,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "you",
              "confidence": 0.98
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "start_time": 1.61,
          "end_time": 2.04,
          "alternatives": [
            {
              "word": "today",
              "confidence": 0.99
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "keywords_result": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

All I want to do is isolate the part where it shows the whole transcript into something like a variable. How would I do this?

Comment: `speech_recognition_results` is a python dictionary, not JSON. Do you know how to parse a dict?

Comment: No idea. I'm assuming that filtering the results has something to do with json because it's using json.dumps.

Comment: You can forget `json.dumps` if you want to parse out a single string. Maybe the [data structures doc](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) will clear things up

Comment: how about `x = speech_recognition_results["results"][0]["alternatives"][0]["transcript"]`